# Angularjs ng grid rendering incorrectly in all browsers

Tags: angularjs

Folks,

I am trying to use the ng-grid component on my webpage.

I have included the following files in my HTML page

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/jquery/jquery.layout-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>  
<!-- Got from the build directory -->   
<script src="lib/angular/ng-grid.js"></script>
```

As for the rest of the code,
I have the following in my controller:

```
 $scope.myData = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                 {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                 {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                 {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                 {name: "Enos", age: 34}];
$scope.gridOptions = { data: 'myData' };
```

I have added the relevant stuff in angular. module declaration too. 
However, the ng-grid gets rendered in the following fashion. Has anyone faced anything similar?

Comment: I actually just checked and I seem to have a problem with just including the regular ng-grid.js from the build folder, so far I've been using the ng-grid.debug.js and that one is working fine.  Also be sure to include the ng-grid.css

Comment: including ng-grid.css did the trick. Thanks shaunhusain